# C# Dynamic Variables from C++ Pointers

Tags: c#, c++

Super simple C# question as I'm trying to pick up the language better. I'm coming from a C++ background and am a little unsure of the solution to not having pointers.

For example, if I wanted a single reference to a variable I would declare it as

```
class Foo{
private:
    SomeClassType* sct;
    SomeOtherClass* soc;
public:
    Foo(SomeClassType* xSct, SomeOtherClass* xSoc) : sct(xSct), soc(xSoc) {}
}
```

So in C# I would have to use I'm guessing either a static reference or maybe some other dynamic allocation way? I don't want 100's of these floating out there.
I can't for the life of me seem to Google the right words to figure this out.

What is the equivalent in C#?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C#'s references would replace your pointers here:

```
class Foo {
  SomeClassType sct;
  SomeOtherClass soc;

  public Foo(SomeClassType xSct, SomeOtherClass xSoc) {
    // Note: No initializer list, we have to do those assignments manually
    sct = xSct;
    soc = xSoc;
  }
}
```

They actually act pretty much the same for most usages (exceptions would be pointer arithmetic, which would be useless here anyway). Access to members of those instances is *always* done with a dot `.` in C#; no `->` like in C++.

In a way you can treat them like C++ references, just that you can re-assign them.

Comment: But every time an object of class Foo is created, won't those two variables get instantiated each time? I would want sct to be a pointer to a given memory address rather than a brand new 'object' being created for instance in a constructor

Comment: Those two fields are unassigned when a `Foo` instance is created. They are `null`. You can assign new instances to them (`sct = new SomeClassType()`) or re-use an instance that is passed in from the outside, e.g. as a ctor parameter: `public Foo(SomeClassType sct) { this.sct = sct; }`.

Comment: Okay gotcha, wasn't sure if they made that the default action for the assignment operator

Comment: I guess you should start with a very light overview of how C# actually works. Coming from a C++ background there are *lots* of things that are different and expecting that nuances are the same is not going to help you. Since you just mentioned assignment operators: Not overloadable and totally predictable in how they work in C#. There's a lot less compiler magic going on for the basic features of the language compared to C++.

Comment: @Joey: I agree with your comment in general but I'm not sure that there is any *less* compiler magic going on, just *different* compiler magic. :)

Comment: @Eric, yes, I thought about that while writing it. But C#'s compiler magic is for the most part with features that were added later, which are not necessary relevant when starting to learn writing programs in that language. E.g. I probably wouldn't start with iterators or `async`/`await`. I learned C++ from a 15 years old codebase (all of it written without C++11 features) with prior experience in C, C# and Java. It probably wasn't the best way of learning the language and I pretty much stumbled over basics most of the time. I'd be willing to say that those aren't as bad in C#.

Answer (score 10):

> Super simple C# question

Actually this is a pretty deep question.

> I'm coming from a C++ background and am a little unsure of the solution to not having pointers.

C# does have pointers but they are almost never used.

> For example, if I wanted a single reference to a variable

**There is the problem right there**.  Stop thinking *I need a reference to a variable, so I need a pointer*.  Yes, pointers are an implementation of references to variables, but that is very much the wrong way to think about it in C#. In C# you *can* make references to variables in a couple different ways, but *you almost never need to*. What you do in C# is make references to *objects*, not to *variables*.

In C#, a value that is of a type that is a *reference type* is automatically a *reference to an object of that type*.

So:

```
class C 
{ 
    public int x; 
}
```

A value of type C is a *reference* to an instance of C; that's what "class" means in C#. So you can then say:

```
class D 
{
    public C c; 
}
```

And an instance of D has a field of type C. That's a variable. The variable's value is a *reference* to an instance of type C.  That instance has a variable x of type int; that variable's value is not a reference to anything, it's just the integer.